# Timer Service Recycle not working properly and OWSTIMER consumes a lot of RAM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, timer-jobs, timer-service, owstimer

We are having a high usage of RAM in our producction enviroment because the timer service isn't recycling (I think).

The Timer Service Recycle is throwing Success in its history, but it doesn't restarts the Timer Job Service, also it doesn't enter the 10 minutes warning proccess, I'm not finding anything in the logs and the time completion for the job shows 00:00:00 and the RAM usage stays the same.

In another server I work, this time stays at 00:10:00 or more, and after that the service restarts and the RAM usage goes down.

Comment: Do you have any custom timer jobs?

Comment: They are all disabled, but we have Nintex, and that brings its timer jobs too, now that I think about it